# Azure CosmosDB - its use as a queue

Tags: message-queue, azure-cosmosdb

I have been doing some reading on Azure Cosmos DB (the new Document DB) and noticed that it allows Azure functions to be executed when data is written to the db.

Typically I would have written to a service bus and then processed the message using an Azure function and storing the message in the document db for history.

I wanted some help on good practice for CosmoDB

Comment: Not sure what, exactly, you're asking. This is very vague. What "good practice" are you referring to? Cosmos DB isn't a queue. And has no built-in mechanisms to manage data the same way Azure storage queues or Service Bus queues handle queue messages.

Answer (score 5):

It depends on your use case, your throughput requirement? what processing you will be doing on data? how transient your data is? will it be globally distributed etc.

Yes, Cosmos DB can ingest data with very high rate and storage can scale elastically too. Azure Functions are certainly a viable option to process the change feed in cosmos db.

Here is more information:  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/serverless-computing-database

Comment: Looks like my previous answer is not enough.

Comment: Looks like my previous answer is not enough. So let me take another take. As I understand the question - can a queue be replaced with data feed reader of Cosmos DB, and the answer is absolutely in some cases. 

Often Queue are placed in front of DB to work as a shock absorbers to handle the sudden peaks. Now Cosmos DB can easily handle the sudden peaks, and you can process the incoming data using the change feed. The link above shows a use case.